# Sending headers after flushing

Tags: php, http-headers, flush

I am currently rewriting the frontend for a site with the purpose of using a facebook-like bigpipe content rendering ( slushing zones after zones in a specified priority )

I have done this, it's ok, but unfortunately because of flushing a zone after another and new rendering order, I echo content and headers invoked in the middle of the script are not beeing sent.

So, to make this as a concrete example: How can I send the headers after I flushed some content ? A simple code :

```
echo $layout;
ob_flush();
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
```

Unfortunately I cannot use things like

```
if(headers_sent()) {
     // use javascript redirect
}
```

because sometimes there are non-redirect headers and there are like 1000 redirect in the site ( yes it is big ).

Can I somehow send the headers after flushing ? Or somehow start the buffer, flush it, empty it, then send the headers -> This would be the best solution.

Or maybe someone can point me in a right direction, this is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send headers before sending any content to browser so you can't do it like in your first example.

Also, check out `headers_sent()` manual page. It doesn't say "some header was sent", it says "all headers was sent and you can't send any more". With use of that function you can check if you can do `Location` redirect or if you have to do it via JavaScript.

Comment: Yea, well unfortunately this does not help me. That was a super simplified example: Real flow is like : render + flush layout -> render + flush zone -> render + flush another zone etc... And there is a header in zone 4 let's say. And I have also said headers_sent() is not an option because I have other headers except location and there are too many location headers to modify them all.

Comment: @Cosmin then you're implementing it wrong. The browser won't start rendering until it received the full DOM anyway, so you must load your "zones" in a separate request. You cannot send a redirect header (or any header for that matter) after outputting any response body, and if you detect you should redirect after rendering four page elements, you're doing something wrong anyway. This answer is the correct answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster 1. I am implementing CHANGES to a code that used normal rendering. 2. Search bigpipe rendering to understand what I want to achieve. One does not need multiple requests to render different zones in order to achieve the ILLUSION of faster site loading.  3. "if you detect you should redirect after rendering four page elements, you're doing something wrong anyway" -> agreed, it's not ok, but consider the fact I am using an existing structure that rendered at the end the output and now I am flushing the content from time to time.

Comment: @Cosmin I know what bigpipe is, and if you think you need send headers halfway rendering a page, you're doing something wrong. It cannot be done.